# How to scale grid values after zooming in MSChart in C++. Net or C#

Tags: c#, c++, mschart

i am using MSChart in VC++.net and my problem is that the zooming function showing double values (the same value twice) and the grid values are not the same of the data that i plotted (the function missed some values).

P.S: it is ok if i get some tipps using C# cuz i'm programming under the .Net enviroment

the function that i use for zoom in:

```
double dZoomFactor = 1.6;

try {  
    xAxisMousePosition = xAxis->PixelPositionToValue(e->X);
    yAxisMousePosition = yAxis->PixelPositionToValue(e->Y);
}
catch (Exception^ e) {
    xAxisMousePosition = (xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum + xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum) / 2.;
    yAxisMousePosition = (yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum + yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum) / 2.;
}

if (e->Delta > 0) // zoom in
{
    double dXToLeft = (xAxisMousePosition - xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum) / dZoomFactor;
    double dXToRight = (xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum - xAxisMousePosition) / dZoomFactor;

    double dYToLeft = (yAxisMousePosition - yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum) / dZoomFactor;
    double dYToRight = (yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum - yAxisMousePosition) / dZoomFactor;

    xAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(xAxisMousePosition - dXToLeft, xAxisMousePosition + dXToRight);
    yAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(yAxisMousePosition - dYToLeft, yAxisMousePosition + dYToRight);
}           
else {
    double dXToLeft = (xAxisMousePosition - xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum) * dZoomFactor;
    double dXToRight = (xAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum - xAxisMousePosition) * dZoomFactor;

    double dYToLeft = (yAxisMousePosition - yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMinimum) * dZoomFactor;
    double dYToRight = (yAxis->ScaleView->ViewMaximum - yAxisMousePosition) * dZoomFactor;

    bool xZoomOutFlg = ((dXToLeft + dXToRight) >= (xAxis->Maximum - xAxis->Minimum));
    bool yZoomOutFlg = ((dYToLeft + dYToRight) >= (yAxis->Maximum - yAxis->Minimum));

    if (xZoomOutFlg)
            xAxis->ScaleView->ZoomReset();
    else
            xAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(xAxisMousePosition - dXToLeft, xAxisMousePosition + dXToRight);

    if (yZoomOutFlg)
            yAxis->ScaleView->ZoomReset();
    else
            yAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(yAxisMousePosition - dYToLeft, yAxisMousePosition + dYToRight);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ok i solved the issue of duplicated values. I did check for the values before i zoom in using Interval

```
int iZoomInterval = 4;

if (((dXAxisMousePosition + dXToRight) - (dXAxisMousePosition - dXToLeft)) > iZoomInterval)
    xAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(dXAxisMousePosition - dXToLeft, dXAxisMousePosition + dXToRight);

if (((dYAxisMousePosition + dYToRight) - (dYAxisMousePosition - dYToLeft)) > (iZoomInterval - 1))
    yAxis->ScaleView->Zoom(dYAxisMousePosition - dYToLeft, dYAxisMousePosition + dYToRight);
```

but i have the problem that the Grid values are not the same what i have plotted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b544B.png)

is it possible to make the Grid value the same as the plotted line? in this example the 655 should be at the red line from Crosshair but it is a little bit above it.